# App Inventor TinyWebDB connect

Tags: database, app-inventor

Can I connect a laptop or desktop to a TinyWebDB service? I need my mobile and laptop to be connected to the same database.

Answer (score 0):

see this link [Creating a Custom TinyWebDB Service](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/tinywebdb.html).

You can access the database using the Service URL, for example  http://appinvtinywebdb.appspot.com is the test service provided by App Inventor.